# How to get the urls which users enter in browsers in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, url

I want to capture URLs which users access via a Windows service created in C#.

Thanks everyone to help about what to do.
actually i want to create a windows service and log all urls which users browse using any browser.

Comment: which browser(s) and what have you tried?

Answer (score 1):

I think  [FiddlerCore](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler/Core/) is the easiest way to create a proxy to monitor the urls

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Fiddler.FiddlerApplication.BeforeRequest += sessionState =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine("URL={0}", sessionState.fullUrl);
        };

    Fiddler.FiddlerApplication.Startup(8888, true, true);

    Console.ReadLine();

    Fiddler.FiddlerApplication.Shutdown();

    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(750);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. You can create proxy app (Any Languages, Easy, Cons: You need to config windows or browsers to use your local proxy)
2. You can hook into all apps and capture winsock calls (C#, C++, Intermediate, Cons: Dirty!)
3. You can create a winsock LSP (C++, Hard)
4. You can use sniffing (C#, Intermediate): http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/17031/A-Network-Sniffer-in-C
5. Using sharppcap (C#, Intermediate): http://sourceforge.net/projects/sharppcap/

Answer (score -1):

1. You need to the Current Context to the service to get request details

or

1. Save the `Request.ServerVariables` when request is being generated and load the data when required

---

Just go through the list of the server variables and save only those which is required
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/2186/A-list-of-Request-Objects-server-variables